# Creating new 'screen' within existing screen

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I have a game server. It runs on linux via dotnet. I run this inside a 'screen' session.
However I am struggling with restarting this server.
From outside, it is easy. I just kill existing screen via name and create new one.
However when I want to restart server from inside (existing game process starts new process that runs script that kills named screen and starts new one)

To be specific:

**stop.sh:**

```
screen -r gameserver -X quit
```

**start.sh:**

```
screen -L -A -m -d -S gameserver /usr/bin/dotnet /gameserver/game.dll
```

**restart.sh:**

```
/gameserver/stop.sh
/gameserver/start.sh
```

Now If I run restart.sh programmatically from inside screen, it calls stop.sh, which terminates current screen and also this restart.sh script, so the new one is not started.

I tried to run restart.sh via screen:

```
screen -L -m -d /bin/bash -c /gameserver/restart.sh
```

But it still doesn't work...
I would expect this to run restart.sh in new screen, where the 'gameserver' screen will terminate and start new one and after that screen running restart.sh will stop. But no :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just kill this process inside the screen? 
Something like

`screen -r gameserver kill $(ps aux|grep 'game.dll'|awk '{print $2}')` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably should NOT run such a script inside screen. Kill the whole session then re-create it inside screen is kind of weird.

And in your script **stop.sh**, though using **-r** with **-X** may sometime work, it doesn't make much sense. I think you should use **-S** instead of **-r**.

**Run outside screen:**

If you replace **stop.sh** with `screen -S gameserver -X quit`, and run **restart.sh** outside screen, it should work.

**Run inside screen:**

However, if you really need to run it inside screen, you could try to kill a window instead of terminate the whole session.

stop.sh:

```
# Create a new window before kill 'server'
# Without this, the session will be terminated if 'server' is the only window
screen
screen -p server -X kill
```

start.sh:

```
# Are we in the 'gameserver' session?
if [ "${STY#*.}" = gameserver ]; then
    # Create a window named 'server' and run your program in it
    screen -t server /usr/bin/dotnet /gameserver/game.dll
else
    # Create a new screen session named 'gameserver' 
    # And it's default window is named 'server'
    # -T $TERM to make sure things such as '-t' work
    screen -L -A -m -d -S gameserver -t server -T $TERM /usr/bin/dotnet /gameserver/game.dll
fi
```